# aws api: assume role access denied

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, assume-role

When I use AWS I switch roles to see client data in the console and it works fine.

[image: example of role switch]

However I'm trying to do it using the `boto3` package in python and running into an "access denied" error. I don't have permission to add an IAM role or edit trust policy in the console, but i feel like i shouldn't need to do this?

Example code and error below:

**initial auth to my acct works fine**

```py
mfa_TOTP = input("Enter the MFA code: ")

sts_connection = STSConnection()

tempCredentials = sts_connection.get_session_token(
    duration=3600,
    mfa_serial_number="arn:aws:iam::123xyz123:mfa/my.name",
    mfa_token=mfa_TOTP
)
print('MFA authentication successful :)')
```

```py
Enter the MFA code: 123456
MFA authentication successful :)
```

**trying to assume a role fails**

```py
account = df.Account[0]
acct_num = account.split('[')[1].split(']')[0]

role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::' + str(acct_num) + ':role/this-user'

sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
assumed_role_object = sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn = role_arn,
    RoleSessionName = account.split(' ')[0]
)
```

```py
ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::123xyz123:user/my.name is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::456abc456:role/this-user
```

Comment: are you not using the tempCredentials received to assume the role

Comment: @steven hurwitt, Checkout my answer, I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to include the temporary credential when assuming the role as below.

```
sts_client = boto3.client('sts', 
   aws_access_key_id= tempCredentials['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], 
   aws_secret_access_key= tempCredentials['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'], 
   aws_session_token= tempCredentials['AWS_SESSION_TOKEN']
)

assumed_role_object = sts_client.assume_role(
   RoleArn = role_arn,
   RoleSessionName = account.split(' ')[0]
)
```

Comment: tried this and still getting the same error, for anyone reading this, i had to call ```tempCredentials.to_dict()``` first.

Comment: tried again and it worked! maybe my mfa was bad last time, thanks so much - i'm dumb

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your policy, to make `sts_client.assume_role` to work, you need to **Allow STS Assume in your Lambda role**. You can add below code in your IAM policy to make it work:

```
{
  "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:iam::*:role/this-user"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow"
}
```

Comment: is the IAM policy in the console under "My Security Credentials" -> "Policies" ? I don't think I have acess to it

Comment: Go to your Lambda function's page. Then "Basic settings" --> click on "Edit" --> A new page will open, below "Existing role" click on the role attached to Lambda. Now a new tab will open. Go there, click on Policy, add the above lines and save it. Come back to lambda and retry.

Comment: ohhh ok so this is actually a python script using the ```boto3``` aws api library